# Ansible in not picking up varibles from group_vars

Tags: ansible

I have created two folders in environments/staging/group_vars  i.e.

1. all/main.yml
2. services/main.yml

When i execute my playbook as below

`ansible-playbook -i environments/staging myplaybook.yml`

Variable defined under group_vars/all/main.yml are being picked up by myplaybook but its not picking up services vars.

Any pointers here ?

Comment: Would you mind posting your inventory?

Comment: Please clarify the use of `services/main.yml`, do you have a group `services` which is required to use vars from that file or do you expect any group of hosts to access it? If later, it's impossible, you should use `group_vars/all` to put globally accessible variables.

Comment: @Andrew services/main.yml is similar to db/main.yml,webserver/main.yml ... I just want to separate out few configurations from group_vars/all/main.yml ...

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I can not post inventory as it has client informations..are you looking something specific ?

Comment: Answer question from @Andrew: _do you have a group `services` which is required to use vars from that file_?

Comment: I dont have... Where do i define that group ?

Comment: is that group "services" need to be inventory file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to separate globally accessible variables to different files (for readability, perhaps), you can store them inside group_vars/all directory under different names, for example:

`group_vars/
  all/
    services.yml
    something_else.yml`

Please refer to official doc: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments, you don't have group `services` defined in your inventory.

Every subfolder in `group_vars` folder corresponds to group name and one for special group `all`.

So for inventory file:

```
[group1]
host1

[group2]
host2
```

`group_vars` may look like:

```
./group_vars/all/common.yml
./group_vars/group1/gr1_specific.yml
./group_vars/group2/gr2_specific.yml
```

So `host1` will have vars from `common.yml` and `gr1_specific.yml`, `host2` – `common.yml` and `gr2_specific.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have environment-specific variables using `children` as follows:

*playbook.yml*

```
hosts: webservers
```

*hosts/development*

```
[webservers]
IP_ADDRESS1
...

[development:children]
webservers
```

*group_vars/development*

```
var1: value1
var2: value2
...
```

*Usage*

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts/development ...etc`